# How to implement Common Music in Common Lisp using Portacle IDE?

Tags: installation, compiler-errors, common-lisp, sbcl

I am currently trying to figure out how to install the Common Music library: http://commonmusic.sourceforge.net/cm2/doc/cm.html, to run on Portacle, an IDE that integrates Emacs among other implementations to run Common LISP.

I was able to successfully download Common Music's source tree to my Portacle installation directory following these steps, found at http://commonmusic.sourceforge.net/cm2/doc/install.html#cvs :

1. Change directories to your Lisp installation directory.

$ cd /usr/local/lisp

2. Set the shell variable CVSROOT to point to the CVS repository:

$ export CVSROOT=":pserver:anonymous@commonmusic.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/commonmusic"

3. Use cvs login to connect to the Sourceforge CVS server, press Enter when prompted for a password:

$ cvs login
CVS password:

4. Use cvs checkout to restore CM's source tree to your Lisp installation directory:

$ cvs checkout -P cm

.

Opening my Common Lisp REPL, portacle, I typed in the equivalent of (load "/usr/local/lisp/cm/src/cm.lisp") for my specific pathname for cm.lisp.

I recieved the following errors.

READ error during LOAD:

Symbol "UNIX-FILE-KIND" not found in the SB-UNIX package.

```
Line: 116, Column: 47, File-Position: 4278

Stream: #<SB-INT:FORM-TRACKING-STREAM for "file /usr/local/lisp/cm/cm.asd" {1004108F23}>
```

[Condition of type SB-C::INPUT-ERROR-IN-LOAD]

.

If anyone is familiar with Common Lisp and integrating Common Music, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this system was written for a different world.  `Unix-file-kind` was removed from `sb-unix` over 10 years ago.

Here, it is used to determine whether a *pathname* names an existing directory.
I am not sure how using `cl-fad` in that system loading context would work (this could be made much simpler nowadays, but that's some work), so maybe you could either inline whatever `cl-fad:directory-exists-p` does, or maybe this works for you (it's a little hacky though):

```
#+sbcl (let ((truename (probe-file dir)))
         (and truename
              (string= (namestring truename)
                       (directory-namestring truename))))
```

You'd replace the line in `cm.lisp` that currently says `#+sbcl (eq :directory (sb-unix:unix-file-kind (namestring dir)))` with this.

… but I expect that this is only the tip of the iceberg.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much! I implemented your edit and was able to move past the first error, but as you mentioned, that was only the tip of the iceberg. Would you happen to have any references or resources you could point me to so that I could begin to further discern the lisp file and eventually move towards implementing my own revisions as to make it a working file? Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, it's difficult for me to tell, I don't know the system nor your background well enough.